# How to scrape the text of all elements with an id containing class_id?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I have the following code that I'm so close to getting working (I think). I can get an array of Selectors containing the values of every anchor element with an `id` containing the string `class_id`. What I'm trying to do is get the text node child of all these anchor elements. Could anyone tell me how to do that? Thanks.

```py
import scrapy;

#with open('../econ.html', 'r') as f:
    #html_string = f.read()

econ_headers = {'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Origin': 'https://pisa.ucsc.edu',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-us',
    'Host': 'pisa.ucsc.edu',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.1.1 Safari/605.1.15',
    'Referer': 'https://pisa.ucsc.edu/class_search/',
    'Accept-Encoding': ['gzip', 'deflate', 'br'],
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

class EconSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "econ"

    def start_requests(self):
   
        urls = [
            'https://pisa.ucsc.edu/class_search/index.php'
            ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, method="POST", headers=econ_headers, body='action=results&binds[:term]=2210&binds[:subject]=ECON&binds[:reg_status]=O&rec_start=0&rec_dur=1000', callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        print(response.xpath('//a[contains(@id, "class_id")] *::text'))
        filename = f'class-{page}.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log(f'Saved file {filename}')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: the `::text` only work with css selectors

`print(response.xpath('//a[contains(@id, "class_id")]/text()').getall())`

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Do you have any recommendations for learning advanced scraping with Scrapy?

Comment: Glad I could help @JohnJacob, I wish I have, we are clearly at the same level, I even copied the code so I can refer to it when I want to use a post request.

Comment: According to the docs, Scrapy is just a thin wrapper for parcel. I found the docs for XPath, which is what parcel is using: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath

Comment: *parsel I meant